# Fourier Series: $a_0$ is undefined?

Tags: fourier-series

I want to find the Fourier cosine series for the following function:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
      x & \text{for}\enspace 0 \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}\\
      \pi-x & \text{for}\enspace\frac{\pi}{2}\leq x\leq \pi
   \end{cases}.
$$

---

**Note:** Since there's so many different versions of it, here's the general Fourier series representation I'm using. If a periodic function $f$ satisfies Dirichlet conditions on $[-L,L]$ and has period $2L$, then we have:

$$f(x) \simeq \frac{a_0}{2}+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(a_n\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}+b_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}\right)$$

where

$$a_n = \frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\cos\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx,\space n = 0, 1, 2, \cdots$$
and
$$b_n =\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}dx, \space n = 1, 2, 3, \cdots$$

---

To get the cosine series we delete the $b_n\sin\frac{n\pi x}{L}$ part of the sum and find a formula for $a_n$. In this case, $L = \frac{\pi}{2}$. I know $f(x)$ isn't defined on $[-L,L]$ but integrating over $[0,\pi]$ is the same. After some wrangling I have:

$$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi}\left(\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}x\cos{2nx}\space dx + \int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}(\pi - x)\cos{2nx}\space dx\right)$$.

After integrating by parts I get:

$$\begin{align}a_n &= \left(\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{1}{4n^2}\right)\left((-1)^n +1+(-1)^n -1\right)\\&=\frac{1}{2n^2\pi}\left(2\cdot(-1)^n\right)\\&=\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\pi}\end{align}$$

(I'm using the fact that $\cos{n\pi} = (-1)^n$ here)

So the Fourier cosine series for $f$ is given by:

$$f(x) \simeq \frac{a_0}{2} + \frac{1}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^2\pi}\cos{2nx}$$

However, when I try to find $a_0$ by subbing in $0$ for $n$ in $a_n$, I run into division by $0$. Is there a method of getting $a_0$ that avoids this?

Comment: What is your calculation of $a_0$? You should use $a_0=\frac{1}{L}\int_{-L}^{L}f(x)dx $.

Comment: Calculate $a_0$ separately. That is, do the integral after plugging in $n=0$.

Comment: The $n=0$ case should be computed separately since it implies $ \cos nx =1$.

Comment: @QC_QAOA So you're saying $a_0 = \frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}f(x)dx$?

Comment: Yes, the $n=0$ case is special is is usually calculated before integration for the exact reason you found

Comment: Okay thanks! Could you give your comment as an answer please so I can mark the question as answered?